# Elasticsearch not generating certificates and enrollment tokens when started from a DockerFile

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, dockerfile, elastic-stack

i'm trying to spin up a docker container for elasticsearch using the Dockerfile:

```
FROM elasticsearch:8.8.1

# Set the environment variables for Elasticsearch.
ENV discovery.type=single-node
ENV xpack.security.enabled=true
ENV ELASTIC_PASSWORD=changeme
ENV http.cors.enabled=true
ENV http.cors.allow-origin="http://local.company.com"
ENV http.cors.allow-methods=POST
ENV http.cors.allow-credentials=true
ENV http.cors.allow-headers=X-Requested-With,X-Auth-Token,Content-Type,Content-Length,Authorization,Access-Control-Allow-Headers,Accept


EXPOSE 9200
EXPOSE 9300
```

But for some reason it is not generating the default certificates in the certs folder (i checked by attaching a shell to the container and in the config folder) neither it is generating password and enrollment tokens. Is anyone aware of this problem?

I tried working without the Dockerfile and the environment variables then it was working. Seems like environment variables are the problem. But they are needed for specifics for my project.